# SignalR update breaks layout and scripts on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, highcharts, signalr

When a SignalR update comes through to our page to update our modal, our item names change and our scripts seem to break.

Brief overview: Our SignalR update gets sent to the website fine, but the data itself has an invalid name.
Once updated, our items refresh with malformed names. Our names shouldn't be updated by SignalR in the first place, and I can't seem to find any references to it in our code.
Closing the modal, our Highcharts and Angular scripts throw console errors.

Server-side code:

```
public partial class Device
{
 if (device != null)
 {
  if ((Enumerables.DeviceType)device.Type == Enumerables.DeviceType.Store)
   SignalrClient.UpdateStore(device.DeviceID);
  else // check if need to update a modal on the dashboard
  {
   foreach (var key in SignalrClient.DevicesDictionary.Keys)
   {
    var devices = SignalrClient.DevicesDictionary[key];
    if (devices != null)
    {
     if (devices.Contains(device.DeviceID))
      SignalrClient.UpdateModal(key, device.DeviceID);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

class SignalrClient
{
 public static async Task Start()
 {
  if (_hubConnection == null || _hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
  {
   _hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://stevessiteofamazingboats.net/");
   _dashboardHubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("DashboardHub");
   _dashboardHubProxy.On("OnRegisterDevice", new Action<string, int>(OnRegisterDevice));
   _dashboardHubProxy.On("OnDeregisterDevices", new Action<string>(OnDeregisterDevices));
   _dashboardHubProxy.On("OnDeregisterDevice", new Action<string, int>(OnDeregisterDevice));
   await _hubConnection.Start();
  }
 }
 public static async void UpdateModal(string connectionId, int deviceId)
 {
  await Start();
  if (_hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
  await _dashboardHubProxy.Invoke("UpdateModal", new object[] { connectionId, deviceId });
  }
}

public class DashboardHub : Hub
{
 private static string EventHubConnectionId {get;set;}
 private AlarmDBEntities db = Utils.DbContext;

 public void UpdateModal(string connectionId, int deviceId)
 {
  var db = Utils.DbContext;
  var device = db.Device.Find(deviceId);
  var modal = new Portal.DeviceModalViewModel()
  {
   DeviceId = deviceId,
   SuctionGroups = device.Device1.Where(x => (Enumerables.DeviceType)x.Type == Enumerables.DeviceType.SuctionGroup).Select(x => new DeviceModalViewModel.SGNode()
   {
   SubChildren = x.Device1.Where(y => (Enumerables.DeviceType)y.Type == Enumerables.DeviceType.Compressor).Select(y => new DeviceModalViewModel.DeviceNode()
    {
    DeviceId = y.DeviceID,
    Name = y.Name,
    Amp = db.Property.Where(z => z.Name == "Amps" && z.DeviceID == y.DeviceID).OrderByDescending(z => z.CreatedOn).Select(z => z.Value).FirstOrDefault()
   }).OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToList()
  }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList(),
 };
}
```

Client-side javascript. The viewModel contains a malformed name:
Viewable on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wmqdyv8r/

This is our Angular console error:

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [ng:areq]    
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?
p0=HeaderController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at angular.min.js:6
at sb (angular.min.js:22)
at Qa (angular.min.js:23)
at angular.min.js:89
at ag (angular.min.js:72)
at m (angular.min.js:64)
at g (angular.min.js:58)
at g (angular.min.js:58)
at g (angular.min.js:58)
at g (angular.min.js:58)

angular.min.js:312 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

This Highcharts error shows up if we try to open a chart after the SignalR refresh:

```
store.js:856 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
at Object.success (store.js:856)
at c (<anonymous>:1:132617)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (<anonymous>:1:133382)
at b (<anonymous>:1:168933)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:173769)
```

Also, after closing the modal, our main page will refresh and now throws this error:

```
Exception: Sequence contains no elements
Type: System.InvalidOperationException
```

The main concern is that the update event is breaking something. The naming issue is a lower priority although I'm sure it's related.

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you trim your code and make a live example, e.g. on jfiddle?

Comment: Just added the JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/wmqdyv8r/, although without the C# it won't fully work, but it should give others a better idea of what's going on.
Also added server-side SignalR code here to also show better detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and fixed the problem!

The malformed name was found to always be trimming the first 5 characters off of the real name, so I fixed that down near the bottom, although I still don't know where this trimming occurs.

The more serious issue, the breaking of scripts was solved as well.
In the UpdateModal method, one of the scripts was looking for a storeID field, along with the deviceID field. After printing a log to the Chrome javascript console, I could see that storeID was always returning 0, even though it was previously initialized before the UpdateModal method.

All I had to do, was <strike>follow the damn train</strike> add the storeID field seen here under DeviceId:

```
public void UpdateModal(string connectionId, int deviceId)
{
 var db = Utils.DbContext;
 var device = db.Device.Find(deviceId);
 var modal = new Portal.DeviceModalViewModel()
 {
  DeviceId = deviceId,
  *THIS*-> StoreId = db.Device.Where(x => device.Name.Contains(x.Name.Replace("-Store", "")) && x.ParentID == null).Select(x => x.DeviceID).FirstOrDefault(),
  SuctionGroups = device.Device1.Where(x => (Enumerables.DeviceType)x.Type == 
  Enumerables.DeviceType.SuctionGroup).Select(x => new 
  DeviceModalViewModel.SGNode()
  {
   SubChildren = x.Device1.Where(y => (Enumerables.DeviceType)y.Type == 
   Enumerables.DeviceType.Compressor).Select(y => new 
   DeviceModalViewModel.DeviceNode()
   {
    DeviceId = y.DeviceID,
    *ALSO THIS*-> Name = "12345Comp " + y.Name.Substring(y.Name.Length - 2),
    Amp = db.Property.Where(z => z.Name == "Amps" && z.DeviceID == y.DeviceID).OrderByDescending(z => z.CreatedOn).Select(z => z.Value).FirstOrDefault()
    }).OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToList()
   }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList(),
};
```